# understanding effect of clause order in full text search query

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm using postgres FTS for prefix searching.
When a match occurs I want to favor an exact match over a prefix match.

A query of `work:*` should order `work` first and then `workday`.
This query will give the same rank for both matches, so this won't work

```
SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'work'), to_tsquery('simple', 'work:*'))
UNION ALL
SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'workday'), to_tsquery('simple', 'work:*'));
-- result:
0.06079271
0.06079271
```

When I add an or clause for `work` ( trough `| work` ) , the rank for `workday` suddenly becomes 0.
I'm not understanding why the or clause reduces the rank to 0, since there is still a matching term (`work:*`) in the query

```
SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'work'), to_tsquery('simple', 'work:* | work'))
UNION ALL
SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'workday'), to_tsquery('simple', ' work:* | work'));
-- result:
0.06079271
0
```

When I switch the two or clauses positionally, the result is the same as not adding the clause at all:

```
SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'work'), to_tsquery('simple', 'work | work:*'))
UNION ALL
SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'workday'), to_tsquery('simple', 'work | work:*'));
-- result:
0.06079271
0.06079271
```

SQL fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/89476

My goal is to better understand `ts_rank` and why the ranking gets impacted in such a dramatic way, potentially reporting any bugs too postgres.

I can not find any mention of the order of the query terms them self to have any impact on ranking.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING

note:
I am using ranking to order the results because my query can contain an arbitrary amount of keywords.

Answer (score -1):

How about a query that explicitly ranks full matches before prefix matches?

```
SELECT doc
FROM tab
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', doc) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'work:*')
ORDER BY NOT to_tsvector('simple', doc) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'work'),
         ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', doc), to_tsquery('simple', 'work:*'));
```

That relies on `FALSE < TRUE`.

Comment: Since my query can contain any number of terms eg:   
`'(work:* | work:* ) & (developer:* | developer )'`  I was hoping to leverage the ranking to sort them based on occurrence.

Comment: Yes, but if `ts_rank` doesn't do what you want, you have to find another way.

Answer (score -1):

```
to_tsquery('simple', 'work:*'), to_tsquery('simple', 'work:*')
```

is the wrong way.  Because :
`select ('simple', 'work:*')::tsquery;` will yield error. So:
`select to_tsquery('simple', 'work:*');` == `select to_tsquery( 'work:*');`

---

why `SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('workday') ,( 'work'::tsquery));` yield `0`   Because `workday` and `work` is two different lexlexemes

---

Translate your question:
why `SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('workday') ,( 'work'::tsquery));`   yield `0`
`select ts_rank(to_tsvector('workday'),to_tsquery('work:*'));`  yield `0.06079271`
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html.
The order is important.

> Ranking attempts to measure how relevant documents are to a particular
> query, so that when there are many matches the most relevant ones can
> be shown first. PostgreSQL provides two predefined ranking functions,
> which take into account lexical, proximity, and structural
> information; that is, **they consider how often the query terms appear
> in the document, how close together the terms are in the document, and
> how important is the part of the document where they occur.**

However there is another function `ts_rank_cd`

```
select ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('workday'),to_tsquery('work | work:*'));
```

return `0.1`

```
select ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('workday'),to_tsquery('work:* | work'));
```

return `0.1`

For now I don't know `0.1` mean.
usefullink: https://linuxgazette.net/164/sephton.html
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/Pine.LNX.4.64.0709111118150.2767%40sn.sai.msu.ru#f5da1024abc8a2fc85814fd49a8bd71d
[http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/NewExtentsBasedRanking](http://www.sai.msu.su/%7Emegera/wiki/NewExtentsBasedRanking)
https://www.postgresql.eu/events/pgconfeu2018/sessions/session/2116/slides/137/pgconf.eu-2018-fts.pdf
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAAMbBLtckoNmFp6irVXsKcZufM6_DiQGN2vtHhWVgofESsE11g@mail.gmail.com

---

`SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'workday'), to_tsquery('simple', ' work:* | work'))`

**The Same as**

```
SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('workday'), to_tsquery(' work:* | work'));
```

please read the manual. I also explained.
If you want simple workday, you need use operator. `'simple & workday'`

Order matters, then the result is inconsistent.
So You want consistent result use  `ts_rank_cd`

Comment: `to_tsquery('simple', 'work:*')` is valid use of ts_query and does not cause an error, it is not clear to me how this relates to the problem/solution. Could you clarify why `SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'workday'), to_tsquery('simple', ' work:* | work'));` returns 0?

Comment: it' valid but it's same as  `select to_tsquery( 'work:*');`,  there is no this way, `to_tsquery('simple', 'work:*')` in the manual.

Comment: The first parameter is the config_name.  Please see this sql fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/89810  See usage here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/textsearch-tables.html. I would encourage you to correct/remove your answer

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer Thanks. I know what simple mean: simple dictionary: just lower case and check for stopword. But still the tsquery order matters, as per manual. here also have examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739215/postgresql-making-ts-rank-take-the-ts-vector-position-as-is-or-defining-a-cust

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer correct me if i wrong. Full text search based on lexemes. I guess that means `select ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'hello'), to_tsquery('simple', 'hell'));` will return 0. 
So `select ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'workday'), to_tsquery('simple', 'work'));` will also return 0.

Comment: Correct, this question specifically is about prefix queries though. So this `SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'workday'), to_tsquery('simple', 'work:*'));` will return `0.06079271`  but somehow this `SELECT ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'workday'), to_tsquery('simple', ' work:* | work'));` returns 0, even though this query matches not less or more terms, why is that ?

Comment: I guess the next step is read the paper or  email to this guy. http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/  But like the manual said ts_rank the order matter. 
and `select ts_rank(to_tsvector('simple', 'workday'), to_tsquery('simple', 'work'));` will return 0.

Comment: Can you clarify in which scenario I would use `simple & workday` ? simple is the dictionary config, how can it be in the actual query ? I really appreciate your answer, but it is super confusing.